# Is the filecmp being removed for Python 3.x? Why?

Tags: python-3.x

According to [this](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/issue12932-dircmp-does-not-allow-non-shallow-comparisons-td662142.html), the filecmp module is removed in 3.x.

Currently (Python 3.2.3), the [filecmp module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/filecmp.html) still exists.

Are there plans to remove this module from Python in the future?

If so, what are the reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not removed, and I can't find any plans to remove it. I suspect Éric is mistaken and probably was thinking of something else, maybe cfmfile? The names are similar.